# Video chat software between 4 stations?

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

Does anyone here know if it's possible to install a software for videochatting, with only 4 contacts available?

I'm going to install 4 Ubuntu PC:s in different locations in a school and want the possibility to video call another station.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to work without a server/an internet connection (e.g., a local network yes, but no connection to the public internet)

Comment: I'm thinking of using it online with a server and internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend "Empathy" - it's the default Chat program and already installed. You might have to install an additional package for video though. [See the wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Empathy)

I think video chat works via [Jabber/XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP), which is a free protocol and there are different servers, for example jabber.org but also Google/Gmail has it's own version of XMPP. [Here is also a list of servers](https://list.jabber.at/)

If you don't want your students to create their own accounts, you can just create pc1-4 accounts and create the friend lists yourself.